# NodeJS How can i read large CSV/Text files from remote server without saving it to disk?

Tags: node.js, node-request

I'm using the `request` module to GET a large CSV file with 70K rows.
However, only ~500 rows are shown in the body.

here is the code:

```
request({
        url: "https://somedomain.com/path/to/file.csv",
        method: "GET"
    } , function (error, response, body) {
        if (error)
            console.error(error);
        else if(body && util.isString(body)){
            let dataArr = body.split("\n");
            console.log(dataArr.length);//Expected 70K, actual ~500
        }
    });
```

I guess i need to use some kind of stream similar to this:

```
request('http://google.com/doodle.png').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('doodle.png'));
```

However, i do not need to save it to disk, I'm using it to build a MongoDB Query e.g:

```
let mongoQuery = {username: {$in:dataArr}}//dataArr should include 70K elements, each element is a string containing up to 60 chars.
```

Can someone points me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it this way: (Although i thought there is a more elegance way on doing it.)

```
    let csvstream = request("https://somedomain.com/path/to/file.csv").pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/file.csv'));
    csvstream.on('finish', function () {
        let instream = fs.createReadStream('/tmp/file.csv');
        let outstream = new stream;
        let rl = readline.createInterface(instream, outstream);

        rl.on('line', function(line) {
            dataArr.push(line);
        });

        rl.on('close', function() {
            //mongoDB call using dataArr.... 
        });
    });
    csvstream.on('close', function () {
        console.log("close");
    });
    csvstream.on('error', function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user Papa Parser to parse a large CSV file:

```
function csvFileData(data) {
    console.log(data);
}

function remoteCSVFileParse(url, callBack) {
    Papa.parse(url, {
        download: true,
        dynamicTyping: true,
        complete: function(results) {
            csvFileData(results.data);
        }
    });
}

remoteCSVFileParse("http://yourRemoteFile.com/Path/filename.csv", csvFileData);
```

Please refer: https://www.papaparse.com/docs#remote-files